# Is there a way to demo / test a Windows Mobile app without Visual Studio 2008 Pro

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

Members in my team needs to test/ see a demo of a mobile app that has been developed.

If they had VS2008 pro then they could use the emulators on this. But they don't. Can they see a demo/test via another avenue/emulator? (apart from on an actual phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the combination of the Device Emulator:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a6f6adaf-12e3-4b2f-a394-356e2c2fb114&DisplayLang=en

and the emulator image for the right WinMo version e. g.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=20686a1d-97a8-4f80-bc6a-ae010e085a6e

will get you to what you need, or at least should get you going in the right direction.